# How to get the exact remainder using modulus in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulus

I want to find the remainder of 23.153 when divided by 23 i.e. 23.153%23. The remainder should come 0.153 but its coming as 0.1529999999999987.

Comment: Take a look at this guide: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: If you always want the same level of precision, say 3 digits, you can get your numbers to print nicely with this: `float("{:0.3f}".format(23.153%23))`, but it's just a hack.

Comment: @pault is this a modification of
 float specific to this answer or to whole program ?

Comment: The _exact_ remainder as you asked can not be obtained in general (Please read the link I provided about floating point arithmetic to understand why). The hack I provided is just a way to force the precision to be what you specify. You format the number as a string to _n_ decimal places (in this case 3) and then convert it back into a string.